# RTK Query calls not initiating before render

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have a couple of query calls that were working previously, but now are not firing off, while the many others I have throughout the app continue to work perfect.  I've done some updating and adjustments elsewhere in the app, but none of which should have affected these calls. On the Redux dev tool, the calls never even show, as if they never happen. The only error I get is from the subsequent data being undefined.

**UPDATE/EDIT**
I've dialed in the issue, but am still confused. If I comment out the call and only display the status (isSuccess, isLoading, isError) the call goes out, completes, and returns success and I can verify the data in the devtools. However if I try to use the data, react is crashing before the data is returned.

Here's one of the calls:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGetUsersQuery } from '../redux/apiSlice';
import { SupervisorTab } from './userviews/SupervisorTab';



export default function Teams() {

    const { data } = useGetUsersQuery()
    const teams = data.filter(e => e.role === "Supervisor")
    
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>Teams</h1>
    {teams && teams.map(t => <SupervisorTab supervisor={t} key={t._id} /> )}
    </div>
    )
}
```

and the corresponding endpoint on the apiSlice:

```
        getUsers:  builder.query({
            query: () => '/userapi/users',
            providesTags: ['User']
        }),
```

I attempted to provide a useEffect hook to only interact with the data once the call is successful, but the same issue is occurring even within the hook.

```
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState()    
    const { data, isSuccess, isLoading, isError, error } = useGetUsersQuery()

    let content
    if (isLoading) {
        content = <h1>Loading...</h1>
    } else if (isError) {
        content = <h1>Error: {error}</h1>
    } else if (isSuccess) {
        
        content = <h1>Success</h1>

    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(data)

       //below are 2 scenarios that illustrate the issue, they're run at separate times...

        setTeams(data)
        //this will provide the correct data, set it to state, and the 2nd log below shows the same.

        const teamInfo = data.filter(e => e.role === "Supervisor") //
        setTeams(teamInfo)
        //this call fails saying data is undefined and the initial console log states undefined
        
    }, [isSuccess])
    console.log(teams)
```

I've not had an issue with this before, typically I put in the query hook, it gets called and completed before the final render, without any UI crash for undefined values. Still, using useEffect, it should only interact with the data once it is available (isSuccess), yet it is crashing during the attempt to interact within useEffect.

I'm ok with React, but have not seen this behavior before. If anyone has a clue as to why or how to resolve, please let me know.

Comment: RTK Query never starts a request before the render (like everything using `useEffect` to start a render), and even if it would, it would never complete before the render as the render is synchronous and the request is async. That's just normal in React. Is that really what you are asking here or am I misreading the question?

Comment: Perhaps my use of terms is off. With useEffect, the data should only be interacting once the call is successful, which reflects if I merely log the data. But if I interact with it (such as with the filter), its crashing saying it is not there. So some process is completing before the data is there, and so my thought was React is attempting to finish rendering before the data is available, but this doesn't make sense since the isSuccess is the trigger in the dependency array

Comment: No, `useEffect` just executes after render, no matter if any request was successful or not - render will also take place if the request has not even started yet. Rendering is synchronous and will immediately take place. The request to the server will always only start after the first render and even then, 20 more renders could take place before the result is there. You misunderstand the dependency array - it will also execute if `isSuccess` is false. You will have to check if it is true in actual code you are writing.

Comment: Thanks, I had got it working by adding the if(isSuccess){} within the useEffect, but yes, I was thinking the dependency array worked like the if condition. Thanks for the clarification.